# Stars and Bars: everyone gets at least one

Tags: combinatorics

In how many ways can we distribute $11$ pieces of candy among $4$ kids, provided that every kid gets at least $1$ piece of candy?

I know how to solve this problem one way, but why does this way not work:

Number of ways to distribute to $4$ people $-$ number of ways to distribute to $4$ people such that at least one person doesn't get any candy

number of ways to distribute to $4$ people (just normal stars and bars): $^{14}C_3$

number of ways to distribute to $4$ people such that at least one person doesn't get any candy: $4\times ^{13}C_2$. This is because we can "merge" two of the bars, and then multiply by $4$ because there are $4$ people whose bars we can "merge".

$^{14}C_3 - 4(^{13}C_2) = 52$.

The answer is $120$.

Comment: "*such that at least one person doesn't get any candy*"  Did you forget that possibly two people didn't get any candy?  Or three?  If you want to approach in this way, you will need to pay attention and use [inclusion-exclusion principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle) properly.

Comment: $\binom{14}{3}-4\binom{13}{2}+\binom{4}{2}\binom{12}{1}-\binom{4}{3}\binom{11}{0}=120$

Comment: Start by giving each kid a candy.  Then distribute the remaining $7$ candies.  $\binom{10}3=120$

Comment: Or just do simple positive-sum stars and bars -- $3$ bar positions chosen from the $10$ gaps inside a row of $11$ candies.